# Get width / height of a GridPane column / row?

Tags: java, layout, grid, javafx-2

While it's obvious how to set the width/height of a column/row in a `GridPane`, how can I actually query these values?

Answer (score 3):

JavaFX8: There is a pack protected method `GridPane.getGrid` to get the current row/col sizes in a two dim double array.You could use reflection to acccess it. In environments with a security mgr, this won't work.

```
public double[][] getCurrentGrid(GridPane gp) {
    double[][] ret=new double [0][0];

    try {
        Method m=gp.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getGrid");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        ret=(double[][])m.invoke(gp);                   

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: that method is package protected for a reason! If it gets removed in a new release, this will be broken all of a sudden.

Comment: I am fully aware of that. But as there is no other convenient way......and there are quite a lot of other areas in FX where you need access to non API methods

Answer (score 1):

In javafx-8 there now is a method called `GridPane#impl_getCellBounds` which will do the trick, although it is part of the internal API. (Not sure if this was also available in javafx-2)

**Note**, as commented by *@olmstov* the mentioned method is depricated and removed in later versions of javafx. If there is a better way (compatible with the public API) it is recommended to use that instead of this alternative.

Comment: impl_getCellBounds is deprecated and will be removed in a future version

Comment: @Olmstov I am aware of that, thats why I explicitly mentioned 'javafx-8' and 'part of the internal API'. Loats of internal API methods have been removed in 'javafx 9+', but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist for 'javafx-8' developers. Although it's better to use other ways if possible due to compatibility reasons, for earlier versions of the API a functionality like this might be only accomplishable by using interal/depricated methods.

Comment: Fair enough. I can remove the down vote if you edit the post. Otherwise it won't let me without some type of modification

Answer (score 1):

<sub>**Disclaimer**: I extracted this from the question, where OP ([**stefan.at.wpf**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298288/stefan-at-wpf)) self-answered it. [Answers should not be contained in the question itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/316262). Also [don't use Edit/Update: Questions/Anwers don't need to record history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/when-is-edit-update-appropriate-in-a-post/127655#127655).</sub>

---

One can add an empty `HBox`/`VBox` to the corresponding `GridPane` column/row and attach listeners to the `HBox`/`VBox` `widthProperty`/`heightProperty`, still I am wondering if there is a way to directly get the width and height of a column / row in a `GridPane`.